# When to case fold and when to collate using Boost.Locale?

Tags: c++, unicode, collation, case-insensitive, boost-locale

[Boost.Locale](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/locale/doc/html/index.html) present different options to perform a case-insensitive comparison of two strings.

Either by using collation through the [`boost::locale::collator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/locale/doc/html/collation.html) facet:

```
int stricmp_using_collation(const std::string& lhs,
                            const std::string& rhs,
                            const std::locale& loc = std::locale())
{
   // secondary level ignores character case but considers accents.
   return std::use_facet<boost::locale::collator<char>>(loc)
      .compare(boost::locale::collator_base::secondary, lhs, rhs);
}
```

or by using case folding through the [`boost::locale::fold_case`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/locale/doc/html/conversions.html) function:

```
int stricmp_using_case_folding(const std::string& lhs,
                               const std::string& rhs,
                               const std::locale& loc = std::locale())
{
   return boost::locale::fold_case(lhs, loc)
      .compare(boost::locale::fold_case(rhs, loc));
}
```

Intermediate results of both functions could be stored and both can thus be optimized if one chooses to do so.

According to the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/locale/doc/html/conversions.html#conversions_notes), case folding is *generally* a locale-independent operation, while collation is an highly locale-dependent operation, as I understand.

- Is there times when the case folding approach would give incorrect results?
  (It's the word "generally" that scares me.)
- Is there times when one is preferred over the other?

Comment: Define "incorrect results" :S. AFAIK the only common locale-dependent tailorings for case-folding involve the Turkish i.

Comment: Those two functions compare differently. `stricmp_using_collation` compares according to the alphabet of the given locale, and `stricmp_using_case_folding` compares according to the alphabet of the global locale. You should use `collator::compare` in `stricmp_using_case_folding` instead of `wstring::compare`. And yes, collation with the `collator_base::secondary` comparison level skips punctuation, when `wstring::compare` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what you want to achieve.

In the collation case (using `collator_base::secondary`), punctuation will be ignored as well. This is sometimes what you want, and sometimes not. So it's up to you to decide, which is to be preferred in a particular case.

The documentations says:

> fold_case is generally a locale-independent operation, but it receives a locale as a parameter to determine the 8-bit encoding.

For me *generally* means in this case, that `fold_case` *is* locale independent, and the locale is *only* used in order to determine the 8-bit encoding. (But I'm not an english native speaker...)